# Neural Network model with keras python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have a question about my NN model. I am using keras from python. My training consists of 1000 samples, each with 4320 features. There are 10 categories, and my Y contains numpy arrays of 10 elements with 0 on all the positions except one.

However, my NN doesn't learn from the first epoch and I probably have my model wrong, it's my first attempt of building a NN model and I must have got wrong a couple of things.

```
Epoch 1/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 40s 40ms/step - loss: 6.7110 - acc: 0.5796
Epoch 2/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 39s 39ms/step - loss: 6.7063 - acc: 0.5800
Epoch 3/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 38s 38ms/step - loss: 6.7063 - acc: 0.5800
Epoch 4/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 39s 39ms/step - loss: 6.7063 - acc: 0.5800
Epoch 5/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 38s 38ms/step - loss: 6.7063 - acc: 0.5800
Epoch 6/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 38s 38ms/step - loss: 6.7063 - acc: 0.5800
Epoch 7/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 40s 40ms/step - loss: 6.7063 - acc: 0.5800
Epoch 8/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 39s 39ms/step - loss: 6.7063 - acc: 0.5800
Epoch 9/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 40s 40ms/step - loss: 6.7063 - acc: 0.5800
```

And this is part of my NN code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4320, input_dim=4320, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

So, my X is a numpy array of length 1000 that contains other numpy arrays of 4320 elements. My Y is a numpy array of length 1000 that contains other numpy arrays of 10 elements (categories).

Am I doing something wrong or it just can't learn based on this training set? (On 1NN with manhattan distance I'm getting ~80% accuracy on this training set)

L.E.: After I've normalized the data, this is the output of my first 10 epochs:

```
Epoch 1/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 41s 41ms/step - loss: 7.9834 - acc: 0.4360
Epoch 2/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 41s 41ms/step - loss: 7.2943 - acc: 0.5080
Epoch 3/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 39s 39ms/step - loss: 9.0326 - acc: 0.4070
Epoch 4/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 39s 39ms/step - loss: 8.7106 - acc: 0.4320
Epoch 5/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 40s 40ms/step - loss: 7.7547 - acc: 0.4900
Epoch 6/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 44s 44ms/step - loss: 7.2591 - acc: 0.5270
Epoch 7/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 42s 42ms/step - loss: 8.5002 - acc: 0.4560
Epoch 8/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 41s 41ms/step - loss: 9.9525 - acc: 0.3720
Epoch 9/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 40s 40ms/step - loss: 9.7160 - acc: 0.3920
Epoch 10/150
1000/1000 [==============================] - 39s 39ms/step - loss: 9.3523 - acc: 0.4140
```

Looks like it starts fluctuating so that seems to be good

Comment: If the classes are mutually exclusive it is more appropriate to use a `softmax` activation and `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function. Also, is your dataset normalized?

Comment: Thank you, I've made your changes. Totally forgot about normalizing the data, did it now and it looks like the accuracy started changing from epoch to epoch (edited the main post). Do you think that the number of neurons in the hidden layer is fine? Is it OK if my accuracy drops in the first epochs ?

Comment: This is something that you would need to tune once you make sure that everything is alright (it is fine for now). Did you try changing the activation and the loss function as well?

Comment: Yes, changed them both

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your categories, classes are mutually exclusive since your target arrays are one-hot encoded (ie you never have to predict 2 classes at the same time). In that case, you should use `softmax` on your last layer to produce a distribution and train using `categorical_crossentropy`. If fact you can just set your targets as `Y = [2,4,0,1]` as your category indices and train with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` which will save you the time of creating a 2 array of shape (samples, 10).

It seems like you have a lot of features, most likely the performance of your network will depend on how you pre-process your data. For continuous inputs, it's wise to normalise it and for discrete input encode it as one-hot to help the learning.